# Result Set of procedure into XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

how can we convert the result set of a procedure into an XML without creating a temporary table since the result set may vary in their structure based on the inputs ? the scenario must work in both on premise and azure hosted SQL server databases.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPSample(@Scope VARCHAR(2)) 
AS 
BEGIN 
   IF(@Scope='A') 
       SELECT 1 AS ID,2 AS NAME 
   IF(@Scope='B') 
       SELECT 1 AS CustomerID,'Sample@sample.com' AS Email,'121314' AS ContactNumber 
END
```

Comment: Please add a sample of your input data and expected result.

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE SPSample(@Scope VARCHAR(2))
AS
BEGIN

IF(@Scope='A')

SELECT 1 AS ID,2 AS NAME

IF(@Scope='B')

SELECT 1 AS CustomerID,'Sample@sample.com' AS Email,'121314' AS ContactNumber

END  So we cant define the table structure in prior right i may have infinite number of conditions and the query may be dynamic which in turn change the columns further.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking to use FOR XML or FOR XML AUTO:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

```
create table mytable(col1 int, col2 nvarchar(20), col3 money)
insert into mytable(col1, col2, col3) values (1, 'string', 123.45)

select * from mytable 
for xml auto
```

Emits:

You can do this on any query result set:

```
select * from sys.objects
for xml auto
```

This will emit that structure similarly.

Comment: i need a way that the result set from a stored procedure directly converted to XML object without creating a table structure since the result set from procedure may vary in their structure so that we can't barely define a table structure. That's why converting directly into an XML format.

Answer (score 0):

> i need a way that the result set from a stored procedure directly converted to XML object without creating a table structure since the result set from procedure may vary

There's no way in TSQL to do that.  TSQL can only convert to XML using a SELECT, not an EXECUTE.  You *could* do this with a loopback linked server or CLR, but those are hacks, and not available in Azure SQL DB.  You'll have to find another way.  EG

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPSample(@Scope VARCHAR(2), @ResultsAsXml bit = 0) 
. . .
```